# Equality of segments in a square

Tags: geometry

"Let $ABCD$ be a square, $K$ any point on the side $BC$, and $M$ the point of intersection of the bisector of the angle $\angle KAD$ with the $CD$ side. 
Prove that:
$DM$ + $KB$ = $AK.$"

I dont have any big clues in this problem, i tried pythagorean theorem, some angles relations but i dont get anything.

Any ideas?.

(The problem is like that, without a drawing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let angel $KAD$ be $2\phi$. So the angle $MAD$ (?) will be $\phi $. Also let the side length of square be $a$. So we have $$MD = a \tan (\phi) \tag{1}$$

Similarly, angle $KAB$ is $90-2\phi$. Thus $$KB = a \tan(90-2\phi) = a\cot(2\phi) \tag{2}$$

The length $AK$ will be $$AK =a \sec(90-2\phi) = a\csc(2\phi)\tag{3}$$

Now we solve the Left Side of equality:
$$MD+KB = a (\tan \phi +\cot 2\phi)\\
 = a\frac{1+\tan^2 \phi}{2\tan \phi} \\
 = \frac{a}{\sin 2\phi}\\
 = AK$$